# How do you use chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener to read API response bodies?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a JavaScript Chrome extension (V3).

I want to be able to detect response bodies from incoming APIs whenever I'm on a website.

I'm using [chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) but I couldn't seem to extract the response body.

Here's my code:

```
const getContent = async response => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      response.getContent((body) => {
        resolve(body)
      })
    }) }

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(async api => {
        if (api.request.url.includes('https://developer.mozilla.org/pong/get')) {
            const responseBody = await getContent(api.response);
            console.log('Response Body:', responseBody);
        } })
```

I'm getting the error that 'getContent' is not a function.

Has anyone built a JavaScript Chrome extension that extracts API response bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the .getContent() method on the variable api:

```
const getContent = async response => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      response.getContent((body) => {
        resolve(body)
      })
    })
}

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(async api => {
    if (api.request.url.includes('https://developer.mozilla.org/pong/get')) {
        const responseBody = await getContent(api)
        console.log('Response Body:', responseBody)
    }
})
```